# How can I avoid using the async keyword everywhere?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Using Javascript, consider the following situation:

- Somewhere **Deep in the call stack**
- Something becomes a **Promise**

This can happen for any number of reasons.

```
// a calls b, calls c, and so on.

function z(){
    // Let's say this:
    // return 4;
    // Became this:
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => resolve(4) );
}
```

Function `Y` can no longer use the `4`, as it's tied up in a promise. Fortunately, Function `Y` can `await` the promise, and then continue business as usual.

However, In order to use `await`, Function `Y` must use the `async` keyword, which forces `Y` to return a promise.

Now, Function `X` must become `async` to `await` `Y`, and Function `W` must become `async` to `await` `X`. On and on it goes, all the way back up the call tree.

In essence, a small change that introduces a promise can require a major refactor.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: No, there is not.  Asynchronous APIs are a fundamental part of JavaScript programming. It's not possible to make it go away.

Comment: that's the thing about asynchrony - there is no way to predict the future

Comment: `However, In order to use await, Function Y must use the async keyword, which forces Y to return a promise.` - You can't use/return a value "returned" from a promise without yourself returning a promise, think about that and why it's an irrefutable fact. Also, it's not a "small" change - your changing a previously sync operation to an async one, depending on how your code is structured that could potentially (as you've discovered) be a massive change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to safely turn an asynchronous method into a synchronous one. This is true for *any* programming language, not just JavaScript.

You *could* transform a Promise into:

1. callbacks
2. an event emitter
3. a stream

You *can* use `.then()` instead of `await`, but you will still have the same problem that asynchrony propagates up the stack to the `main()` method unless you do one of the above options.

Once you start using asynchrony, it necessarily "poisons" any of the callers unless you throw away the result. Avoiding the use of the async/await keywords isn't getting rid of the asynchrony, it's just represented in code in a different form.

Answer (score 0):

Don't recommend you this path, but try something like  below maybe:

```
function Y(retVal) {
    if (retVal instanceof Promise){
        return (async function(){
            var result = await retVal;
            return  Y(result);
        }());
    } else {
        return retVal * 2;
    }
}

Y(4) //8;
Y(Promise.resolve(4))  //{<resolved>: 8}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this resolves OP's problem. Values are still wrapped in a promise

Comment: Well it kinda solves it because you don't care anymore what the functions return. His problem is he had to use async everywhere, now he only uses once within the function. correct?

Comment: If OP wants to remove the async keyword, this is a terrible way of doing it - `return 'then' in retVal ? retVal.then(x => x * 2) : retVal*2` would have the same effect and would be much easier to read. But the value is still wrapped in a Promise, which appears the issue OP has. There's no way to "fix" that

Comment: Terrible is an adjective, means nothing. It's basically the same. 1 * instanceof + iife async VS twice property access + calling lambda. Congrats you made it shorter to JIT compile. BS nitpicking, nothing else.

Comment: It's also a *lot* easier to read. Legibility is not BS nitpicking. There's no reason to use recursion here, nor an IIFE

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of way to handle promises like you can use async-await, .then(), so if any new promises comes in deep call stack and you don't have any options to use async-await then use Promises.then() method